# Where can I find a replacement faucet sprayer hose?

Tags: repair, faucet, hose

My kitchen sink sprayer is broken and I need to replace the hose.  The hose has an unusual connection that clips into a plastic piece; but doesn't seem standard compared to what I've seen as replacements.  Anyone familiar with where I can get a replacement hose like this?

[image: End of hose]

[image: Faucet receiver]

Comment: How about a faucet brand name, to begin with?

Comment: See the [meta discussion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details about our product recommendation policy.

Answer (score 1):

That's a Quick or Snap Connect connection. They might be a little difficult to find, but there should be a few in the Home Improvement stores or online of course. Or, you can just replace the black rubber O-rings if it was just leaking.